# Failed to enable constraints using TableAdapters

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, tableadapter

I'm trying to check if a username exists in my table when everytime a character is entered in the `TextBox`. Here is my code:

Within the `register.aspx.cs` file I have a `TextChanged` event on the `TextBox`:

```
protected void username_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string check = authentication.checkUsername(username_txt.Text);

    if(check == "false")
    {
        username_lbl.Text = "Available";
    }
    else
    {
        username_lbl.Text = "Not Available";
    }
}
```

It calls this method:

```
public static string checkUsername(string Username)
{
    userInfoTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter userInfoTableAdapters = new userInfoTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter();
    DataTable userDataTable = userInfoTableAdapters.checkUsername(Username);
    DataRow row = userDataTable.Rows[0];
    int rowValue = System.Convert.ToInt16(row["Users"]);

    if (rowValue == 0)
    {
        return "false";
    }
    else
    {
        return "true";
    }
}
```

The query that is being executed is:

```
SELECT COUNT(username) AS Users FROM users WHERE (username = @Username)
```

For some reason, it keeps breaking on this line:

```
DataTable userDataTable = userInfoTableAdapters.checkUsername(Username);
```

It gives an error that says:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Just incase, the username field in my table is Unique and Not Null, I have tried just executing the query itself and it works perfectly so it isn't at the query end.

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't return the row - so using a `TableAdapter` query that returns the `DataTable` is inappropriate in this case.

I'd recommend using your query with something like the function below.  I took the liberty of actually returning boolean....

```
public static bool checkUsername(string userName)
{

SqlClient.SqlCommand withCmd = new SqlClient.SqlCommand();

bool result = false;

withCmd.Connection.Open();

    withCmd.CommandType = CommandType.text;
    withCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS Users FROM users WHERE (username = @Username)"
    withCmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 16)).Value = userName;

try {
    int intResult;
    object scalarResult = withCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if ((scalarResult != DBNull.Value)
       && (scalarResult  != null)
       && (int.TryParse(scalarResult, out intResult)))
                  result = (intResult==1);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    result = false;         // hmm, bad...can't tell handle error...
} finally {
        // only close if we opened the connection above  ...
        withCmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}

return result;
}
```

A TableAdapter does support scalar queries on the Table Object, when you add and name your query, check the properties of that query and be sure its `ExecuteMode` is Scalar.  It will then return the integer value, not the row!

[image: TableAdapter with Scalar Query showing properties]

On the other hand, if you want to keep your structure, change the query to actually return the `row`, something like

`SELECT uu.* AS dbo.Users uu FROM users WHERE (username = @Username)`

and make the result of the checkUsername() function depend on the number of rows returned (which should be 1 or zero....)

Comment: I don't understand? I took the EXACT same approach in a project created on Visual Studio 2010, I am currently using 2013 so maybe they've changed a few things?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to be selecting all is simply because it'll just be querying and irrelevant data that I don't need...

Comment: There is a way to do this with a query added to a TableAdapter - but not if you try to use DataTable userDataTable as the result. The simple reality is that SELECT COUNT(*) does not return a DataRow that fits into userDataTable -- hence the constraint exception. I have updated the answer to try and show the TableAdapter with a scalar query - but that is harder to document here.

Comment: Looking to see if this question had a better answer elsewhere, I ran across this MSDN reference on 'How to: Create TableAdapter Queries', see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx